# Usage of multiple text names in CASE... WHEN Statement after THEN (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, case, case-when

I have got stuck in writing the SQL stored prosedure in MS SQL Server Management Studio 2005

The table looks like following

```
[Quantity] | [Plant]
        10 | Apple
        20 | Carrot
        30 | Lemon
        40 | Orange
```

The procedure looks like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.PLANTS
where [Plant] in (@Name)
```

What am I trying to do is set @Name='Fruits' and get all the fruits from the table plants.
So I wrote something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.PLANTS
where [Plant] in 
(
Case
when @Name='Fruits' then ('Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange')
)
```

Obviously it didn't work. Is there any way such trick *may* work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.PLANTS
where 
  (@Name='Fruits' and [Plant] in ('Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange'))
```

If you'll want to select other things based on `@Name`, you could do that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.PLANTS
where (@Name='Fruits' and [Plant] in ('Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange'))
   or (@Name='Vegetables' and [Plant] in ('Tomato', 'Onion', 'Cucumber'))
```

However, it's best that you make this more explicit in the data itself and add a `Catergory` column, as [Aaron pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18187923/390819).

Answer (score 1):

You could re-write it this way:

```
WHERE @Name = 'Fruits' AND Plant IN ('Apple','Lemon','Orange')
```

But much better would be to add a category to the other table and make a simpler join, this way you don't need to keep a list of fruits and a list of veggies hard-coded in your stored procedure.

Comment: I would definitely do so, but, unfortunately, this is the client's database, and I cannot change it. After the client expanded his list of departments I am trying to avoid re-making complex Xcelsius file by changing the procedure that gets information for it - so the names will get hardcoded anyway. Thank you for your advice anyway!

Comment: Yes, I tested it and found out that this suits me perfectly well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.PLANTS
WHERE (@Name='Fruits' and Plant in ('Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange')) or
      (@Name = Plant);
```

You don't need the `case` statement to generalize this.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.PLANTS
WHERE (@Name='Fruits' and Plant in ('Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange')) or
      (@Name = 'Tropical' and Plant in ('Orange', 'Lemon', 'Mango')) or
      (@Name = Plant);
```

However, if you have too many choices you should put the mapping between "Name" and plants in a separate table.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't get Aaron's advice and used your code as starting point. You broke it down really well.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.PLANTS
where [Plant] in 
(
Case
when @Name='Fruits' then ('Apple', 'Lemon', 'Orange') end
)
```

have you tried putting the END keyword?
or try to put a column as a category to make it more easier